# How to preserve list values after linq operation?

Tags: c#, linq, azure

I am querying azure table. After getting the data I am performing linq select operation and getting modified values.
But I want two lists one with old values and other with new values.

```
var oldUserEntities = userEntities.ToList();
var newUserEntities = userEntities.Select(i => { i.RowKey = dict[i.RowKey]; return i; }).ToList();
```

After this code if I verify values in oldUserEntites and newUserEntities, both having same modified values. 
How to have old list and new list?

Comment: Try using
oldUserEntities .Select(i => { i.RowKey = dict[i.RowKey]; return i; }).ToList();

Comment: What exactly you try to select with `.Select()` method ?

Comment: What is the type and source of `userEntities`?

Comment: userEntities are of type "DynamicTableEntity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `i` in your projection is referencing the original item in `oldUserEntities`, then `i.RowKey` is modifying the original data.

Try this instead (assuming your entity is named `UserEntity`):

```
var oldUserEntities = userEntities.ToList();
var newUserEntities = userEntities.Select(i => new UserEntity
{
    RowKey = dict[i.RowKey],
    // rest of desired properties ...
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, but this

```
> i => { i.RowKey = dict[i.RowKey]; return i }
```

is changing RowKey on every object in the list. The "return i" is then making a list containing the same, now modified, objects.

all this is really doing is

```
foreach(i in userEntities)
  i.RowKey = dict[i.RowKey]
```

and then making a copy of the list